# How many nations are there in the Naruto universe?

Tags: naruto

How many total countries are present in the *Naruto* universe, including small or less significant ones? Are there only the five nations which participated in the war?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are for sure more than the big five nations. I never watched a single episode of Naruto, but I will try to provide an answer here. You only ask for the nations, but I will add a list of the villages too.

[image: Map]

<sub>This [map is made by xShadowRebirthx](http://www.deviantart.com/#/art/Elemental-Nations-Geographical-Map-317422439?hf=1). **This is not a official map and also some places could be differ from the original!** Click on the image to enlarge the map.</sub>

The countries in Naruto operate as separate political entities and are presumably all monarchies, ruled by feudal lords who stand equally in rank with the hidden villages' leaders.

### The great five countries

Five of the countries are considered to be the most powerful and influential of them all.

- Land of Earth

[image: Earth]

> The country is mostly comprised of desolate, rocky areas. The border
>   of the Land of Earth runs along a rocky mountain range, blocking
>   communication with other countries. The wind blowing from the north
>   passes over these mountains, carrying small rocks from the Land of
>   Earth to the surrounding countries.

- Land of Fire

[image: Fire]

> The Land of Fire is appropriately oriented towards the element of
>   fire, typically having very bright and warm weather. While not the
>   physically largest country, it has the largest hidden village.

- Land of Lightning

[image: Lightning]

> In the centre of the country are vast mountain ranges, whose many
>   thunderstorms are said to give the country its name. From these
>   mountain ranges, many rivers flow to the sea, creating a very crooked
>   coastline that displays an impressive oceanic beauty. There are many
>   hot springs located within the country.

- Land of Water

[image: Water]

> The country's weather is typically cool and the islands are usually
>   covered by mist. The islands themselves also feature many lakes. The
>   nation is oriented towards the element of water.

- Land of Wind

[image: Wind]

> The country covers a vast realm, but that realm is largely composed of
>   deserts. Because there is very little rainfall throughout the year,
>   the people of the country live in villages built on one of the
>   desert's many oases. Despite the country's extremely harsh
>   environment, it has a large population.

So there are all countries listed, here are four more of the bigger ones

- Land of Iron
- Land of Snow
- Land of Sound
- Land of Sky

### Minor countries

[image: Minor]

I also found some other wich I could not assign to a catagory. These are the *Land of Grass*, *Land of Rain*, *Land of Read Beans*, *Land of Rice Fields*, *Land of the Waterfall*, *Land of Udon* and *Land of Waves*.

### Shinobi Villages/Hidden Villages

Shinobi villages, or also called hidden villages, are ninja villages that serve as the military force for their country.

[image: Hidden Villages]

In summary, there are the 5 big nations, the 4 smaller one which make 9 nations. There are 28 minor countries (or 7 more if you count the not categorized countries) and 31 hidden villages.

<sub>Most of the information are from the [Narutopedia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Geography). Other information from the frozen site [narutoarikiri](http://narutoraikiri.webs.com/narutocountries.htm). A cached version is available [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130710000331/http://narutoraikiri.webs.com/narutocountries.htm).</sub>

Comment: with Minor countries i think most can be prefixed with "Land of " though i don't know if this is a set fast rule on all Minor countries isn't aren't suffixed with " Island"

Comment: @Memor-X yea your right. I did not wrote that because it would not readable anymore. And I also did not want to write them in a list because you have to scroll so long. I have put them into a table now and I also found some more :3

Answer (score 1):

There is definitvely more than 5 countries. You can find all the countries on this site:

**([from Waybackmachine](http://web.archive.org/web/20130710000331/http://narutoraikiri.webs.com/narutocountries.htm))**

Comment: The website is frozen (will this site up again?). Therefore it is not an answer! You should edit it. It is also not a good idea to provide links without the actual answer here. You should answer here and than link to the source.

Comment: I managed to save the answer or well the link anyways. If a site is frozen then their will most likely be a cached version of it complete on [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/).

Comment: @Izumi-reiLuLu This is also only a temporary solution. The answer should be provided on this site. It is only a question of time and also this site could be break, moved or the cache gets updated or whatever.

Comment: @Gerret- In short I think this answer should probably be deleted anyways. It only relies on a link (which is frozen and doesn't work and also who's to say waybackmachine will stay open forever too).

Comment: @Izumi-reiLuLu Yes I think so! I write at the moment a answer and provide a long lasting source (hopefully)

Comment: -1 for the perfect example as to why we want people to explain what's in the links, in case if the site does go down

Answer (score 1):

First there are the 5 villages:

- Leaf
- Sand
- Stone
- Mist
- Cloud

Then the hidden villages:

- Waterfall (Kakuzu)
- Steam (Hidan)
- Rain (Pain and Konan)

Don't forget hidden Sound and Grass. Then the Uzumaki village and hidden Frost village.

Also in the Naruto manga (I forgot what book but the one with Edo Haku and and Edo Sasori), it says that the main hidden villages asked hidden Frost and Steam to move to a safer place, so it was somewhat involving them. Then when Sasuke revived Orochimaru they went to the battle field with Karin Jugo and Suigetsu (and the past hokages), this doesn't count as hidden Sound.

Comment: There are alot more than these you listed here...